# All I do is carry out orders and obey. Who am I?

Tags: riddle, poetry

Some will understand what I say, some do not.
I speak the exact words you want.
Some words I speak however, you would like not.
For you to understand me, you shall study a lot.

I carry out your orders, exactly what you say,
I may make mistakes, but it is not my fault.
You will understand me maybe after an hour,
maybe after a month!

You will be mistaken, when you hear my name
I don't gather things from here and there.
No, that is so lame.
I do serious business,
 
Carrying out orders and translating is my game.

Can you guess who I am?

Comment: A compiler?????

Comment: @Daedric I didn't expect it that quick :)

Comment: @Daedric try and work it out and post an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess:

> A compiler

I speak the exact words you want

> Only does what you program it to do.

I may make mistakes, but its not my fault

> Code maybe wrong, therefore its not really wrong the programmer is.

You would not like what I say / would need to study a lot.

> Binary / Machine code maybe require studying to learn / people might not like the complexity of either?

When you hear my name you maybe confused, I dont gather.

> Could mean to gather, might cause confusion to those without programming knowledge.

Etc.